# Office 365 Starter Project error when applying subject filter to mail query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365api

I'm using the starter project found at https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start/blob/master/README.md

I can run the project and retrieve mail, but when I modify this method...

```
internal async Task<List<model.MailItem>> GetEmailMessages(int pageNo, int pageSize)
```

by adding the where clause below...

```
var mailResults = await (from i in outlookServicesClient.Me.Folders.GetById("Inbox").Messages
                                 where i.Subject == "test"
                                 orderby i.DateTimeReceived descending
                                 select i).Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ExecuteAsync();
```

I get this error...

> AdalException This exception is thrown when either you have a stale O365 access token that can cause authentication errors, or you attempted to access a resource that you don't have permissions to access.

I've started and restarted the project several times. If I remove the where clause, it works again. If I add the where clause back, it fails again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing where and orderby, you're trying to do a composite query,

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Folders('Inbox')/Messages?$filter=Subject eq 'Test'&$orderby=DateTimeReceived desc&$skip=0&$top=10
```

The v1.0 outlook server RESTful API does not support such composite filter. It deems it as an "InefficientFilter", by giving such error message,
"The restriction or sort order is too complex for this operation".

You can workaround this by doing the sort at client side, possibly reduce network traffic, like below,

```
var mailResults = await (from i in outlookServicesClient.Me.Folders.GetById("Inbox").Messages
                                 where i.Subject == "test"                                   
                                 select i).Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ExecuteAsync();

var mailMessages = mailResults.CurrentPage.OrderByDescending(i=>i.DateTimeReceived);
```